# ShiftVector template class - 'Symbol(s) not found'

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I've created a class that's designed to rotate a vector. (I realize this functionality basically already exists in STL, I'm just trying get a handle on template classes.)

My specification file:

```
template <class T>
class ShiftVec {
private:
    vector<T> vec;

public:
    ShiftVec(vector<T>);
    vector<T> getVec();
    void shiftRight(int);
    void shiftLeft(int);
};
```

My implementation file:

```
template <class T>
ShiftVec<T>::ShiftVec(vector<T> v) {
    vec = v;
}

template <class T>
vector<T> ShiftVec<T>::getVec() {
    return vec;
}

template <class T>
void ShiftVec<T>::shiftRight(int n) {
    rotate(vec.begin(),
           vec.end()-n, // this will be the new first element

template class ShiftVec<int>;
template class ShiftVec<double>;
template class ShiftVec<bool>;
template class ShiftVec<string>;
```

When I run this, I get a bunch of errors that look like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ShiftVec<int>::shiftRight(int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "ShiftVec<int>::getVec()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "ShiftVec<int>::ShiftVec(std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm not sure exactly what's going wrong here. A push in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: Did you make the mistake of compiling the template implementation file separately?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare **each** of the templated functions WITH the type as well in the implementation file.

For example:
For your implementation:

```
template <class T>
ShiftVec<T>::ShiftVec(vector<T> v) {
    vec = v;
}
```

You should add a line under the implementation like so:

```
template <class T>
ShiftVec<T>::ShiftVec(vector<T> v) {
    vec = v;
}
template ShiftVec<int>::ShiftVec(vector<int> v); // <<< this is the line added
```

The final line above is key  here.

Comment: I've added several versions(types) of the `ShiftVec()` class, but I'm getting a `Thread 1: BAD_EXC_ACCESS` error now.  (I edited my question with the changes)